# Show that this mapping is an isomorphism between the vector space $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{K}}(n,p)$ and $L(\mathbb{K}^p,\mathbb{K}^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I am considering the mapping $ u : \mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{K}}(n,p)\to L(\mathbb{K}^p,\mathbb{K}^n) : M\mapsto l_{M} $ and I would like to show this is a vector space isomorphism.

I should mention that $l_{M}(X) = MX$ where $X\in\mathbb{K}^p$ and $M\in\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{K}}(n,p)$

First, I want to show that :

$\forall A,B\in\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{K}}(n,p)\times\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{K}}(n,p),\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R} : u(\alpha A+ B) = \alpha u(A) + u(B)$

Since $u(A)$ and $u(B)$ are functions of elements in $\mathbb{K}^p$, the previous equality needs to hold for all $X\in\mathbb{K}^p$.

In fact, the set $L(\mathbb{K}^p,\mathbb{K}^n)$ is a vector space for the addition of vector and multiplication by a scalar that is defined on the image of the mapping of this set.

But for all $X\in\mathbb{K}^p$ we have :

$u(\alpha A + B)(X) = (\alpha A + B)X = \alpha AX + BX = \alpha u(A)(X) + u(B)(X)$

So it is a linear mapping. Now we need to show that $u$ is bijective.

Consider $Z\in Ker(u) = \left\{ X\in\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{K}}(n,p) : u(X) = 0_{m} \right\}$ where $0_{m}\in L(\mathbb{K}^p,\mathbb{K}^n)$ is the null mapping. It means that :

$\forall X\in\mathbb{K}^p : u(Z)(X) = ZX = 0_{n}\implies Z = 0_{n,p} $ which shows that $u$ is injective.

Now, to show that it is bijective, I don't have any idea except the one consisting to show that the rank of $u$ is equal to the dimension of $L(\mathbb{K}^p,\mathbb{K}^n)$ but I don't know how to proceed ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done looks good. As you said it remains to show that the mapping is surjective.

Therefore let $l : \mathbb K^p \rightarrow \mathbb K^n$ be a linear map. By considering the canonical basis of $\mathbb K^p$ and $\mathbb K^m$ then you can find a matrix $M_l$ such that for all $X$ you get

$$ M_lX = l(X).$$
That is, you can find $M_l$ such that  $u(M_l) = l.$

Comment: Wow, this is very clear !! Moreover what you have donne works for any $l\in L(\mathbb{K}^p, \mathbb{K}^n)$ since by the fundamental property of linear mapping you can always "bring back" a linear mapping to the canonical basis of the space on which is defined this mapping ! Thank you a lot really !!